# авторизация пользователя (подход к реализации)

Tags: android, авторизация, аутентификация

Добрый день!
Требуется консультация по корректному подходу к реализации авторизации, хранения и использования данных пользователя.

1 - Приложение (не имеет/не требуется доступ в сеть), список пользователей/паролей предполагаю хранить в базе локально.

2 - Несколько пользователей в приложении необходимы для разграничения доступа к информации в пределах одного устройства.

3 - При переходе между Activity, требуется передавать/хранить userId (по данному id выбираются данные именно этого пользователя).

4 - Необходим доступ:
  а - без ввода пароля, для дефолтного пользователя например после установки приложения.
  б - по логину/паролю.
в - без ввода пароля (автоматический вход), для конкретного пользователя (указав данный параметр в настройках)

Предполагаю, что, при вводе логина/пароля проверяю наличие логина и корректность пароля (выполнять это просто запросом к базе через метод?)

Далее нужен класс(нужен ли?), объект которого необходимо создавать при прохождении авторизации и заполнять данными.

При переходе между Activity постоянно передавать userId, или использовать глобальную переменную?

реализовать могу, как правильно не понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При переходе между Activity постоянно передавать userId, или использовать глобальную переменную?

По поводу userId - я бы его записывал в [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) после успешной авторизации и брал от туда при смене активити.

> Предполагаю, что, при вводе логина/пароля проверяю наличие логина и корректность пароля (выполнять это просто запросом к базе через метод?)

Да как вам удобнее так и делайте. Как то сильно заморачиваться с этим имеет смысл только если вам нужна большая секьюрность и надо противостоять хакам на устройстве и реверсинженерингу.

> Далее нужен класс(нужен ли?), объект которого необходимо создавать при прохождении авторизации и заполнять данными.

Нужен для чего? Как по мне нужен только userId. Если он задан - то в нем ид пользователя, если нет - значит пользователь не авторизован.

Comment: А на счет четвертого пункта? Как разделить отображение файлов для разных уровней доступа? Пилить три активности с тремя разметками, или делать одну активность (но все с теми же тремя разметками), но через `if` проверять, какую разметку ставить и какие вьюшки доступны, а далее уже выбирать действие?

Comment: По 4му пункту, (приложение отображает только данные из базы, в базе зафиксированы userId для данных). Исходя из предложенного варианта с хранением в SharedPreferences, думаю нужно использовать ключи (int) userId и (int) useAutoAuthorization. Если useAutoAuthorization = true и userId = -1 , то автовход дефолтным юзером без запроса пароля, Если  useAutoAuthorization = false и userId = не указан, то вход через логин/пароль. Если  useAutoAuthorization = userId, то вход без пароля для соответствующего пользователя.

Comment: Касательно класса, согласен перебор, в моем случае userId полностью самодостаточен.

Для контроля доступа по таймауту бездействия и повторного входа (через пароль, если необходимо). добавлю в SharedPreferences время выполнения onStop. В onStart проверяем достигнут таймату или можно работать без ввода пароля.